# Targeting generic-named div attribute using relative level position

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have this kind of div hierarchy:

```
<div class="student">
    <div class="name">Alex</div>
    <div class="details">
         <div class="status"></div>
         <div class="score">90</div>
    </div>
<div>
<div class="student">
    <div class="name">Benny</div>
    <div class="details">
         <div class="status"></div>
         <div class="score">60</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

If I have this kind of checking:

```
If (parseInt($('.score').text()) > 80) {
    // set status div value to pass
    // set name color to red
}
```

But all I have is only this structure of generic, class-named divs. How if I want that the jQuery code will result in only Alex name become red and status become pass, and Benny will be unaffected, but my starting point will be from detecting the div with the score? So I hope I can understand how to target the siblings and the parents of the score div, without the need to browse and loop all from the root. I'm looking for something maybe like `$('.score').parent` or `$('.score').sibling('.status')` or `$('score').parent.child('.status')` if that's even exist. I hope jQuery has feature like that. But if not, please give the closest way possible to target relative tags according to you. Thanks.

Comment: Pardon me. I've just do quick search and found out that .parent() do exist. For now, just think that I've found the solution, and ignore this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.score').each(function(index){
    if(parseInt($(this).text()) > 80){
        $(this).parent().children('.status').text('pass');
        $(this).parent().parent().children('.name').css('color','red');
    }
});
```

1. You can't use an if() on the outside of the jQuery selector because you have multiple elements you need to loop through.
2. <s>Your selector should be `.score .score` as you have the actual score nested as such.</s>
3. to loop through the multiple selected elements, you use jQuery's "each"
4. You can use "parent" and "children" functions to navigate around in your DOM

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/62a31psg/

Comment: Hi. It was actually a mistake of me when writing the code because the outer "score" should be "details". I tried as quickly as possible to edit the codes, but it looks like you've already read it by the time I change it. But it's alright, I actually learn something new about the .score .score. Thank you very much for showing that this actually is possible (wrote two selectors beside each other to select a selector inside another selector). Thanks for the notes. I kinda new on this jQuery, and this helps me much. Btw, isn't that the css code should be `css ({'color':'red'});` ? Thanks.

Comment: If you are planning on setting multiple css properties, you can do so by passing an object just like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all the div's who's class name is `student` and check it's children's `score` div with your passing score. Try this,

```
$(".student").each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).children(".details").children(".score").text()) > 80){
        $(this).children(".name").css("color", "red");
        $(this).children(".details").children(".status").text("Pass");
    }
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/L3yLm85d/)

Comment: Yeah, I thought I can use the if directly and the if will be run for each of the instance. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$('.score').each(function(){
  if(parseInt($('.score').text()) > 80) {
    //get parent student div
    var parentDiv = $(this).closest('.student');
    //find name and status div to change property
    $(parentDiv).find('.name').css('color','red');
    $(parentDiv).find('.status').text('Pass');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! May I asked about the `closest` function, can it check for siblings? Or does it only check for parents? Many thanks!